# Mako, use if / else control structure in one line

Tags: python, mako

I would like to do something like this, restricted on on line. I can't use multi line.

`% if object.lang == 'fr_FR': 'Rappel de paimenet'  % else: 'Payment reminder' %endif`

I know that this is not the good syntax, but I did find in the documentation how I coiuld manage to do it ?

Cheers

Comment: There is an [old doc from Indico](https://getindico.io/legacy-docs/wiki/Dev/Technical/UsingMako.html) which proposes alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [don't think you can do this with Mako](http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/syntax.html), at least not in the way you want.

> The % can appear anywhere on the line as long as no text precedes it;

One way you can do this is to not put the if-statement in the template. It seems you are trying to use a translation, so make the translation in the code you are using to feed the template:

```
text = 'Rappel de paimenet' if object.lang == 'fr_FR' else 'Payment reminder'
# Now your template doesn't need to use an if-statement
template = Template("""Status: {{text}}""").render(text=text)
```

Since it appears that you are using this for translations, I would look into using [gettext](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gettext.html#gettext) and [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/). If you are using this in a web application, look into any translation-specific utilities (such as [django-babel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-babel/0.3.1) or [flask-babel](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I took this approach and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pure python.

```
var = {True: newValueIfTrue, False: newValueIfFalse}[condition]
```

It should be easy to wrap it in a template.

Answer (score 0):

We need to use "\n":

```
tmpl = "% if object.lang == 'fr_FR':\n 'Rappel de paimenet'\n  % else:\n 'Payment reminder'\n % endif"
```

If we use file template, we need to expand "\n". As commented in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75132308/2755116) and [unicode Chapter in official Mako documentation](https://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/unicode.html), one solution could be:

```
t2 = Template(filename="test.tmpl", output_encoding='utf-8')
result = t2.render(object.lang="English").decode("unicode_escape")
print(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
${object.lang == 'fr_FR' and 'Rappel de paimenet' or 'Payment reminder'}
```

Or if you want to extend it to more languages, with english as the default:

```
${{'fr_FR': 'Rappel de paimenet', 'es_ES': ...}.get(object.lang, 'Payment reminder')}
```