# Make a conditional in mako template in one line

Tags: if-statement, mako

I have this template in [Mako templating system](https://www.makotemplates.org/):

```
from mako.template import Template

tmpl = """
% if name:
Hello ${name}
% else:
Hello world
% endif
"""

t = Template(tmpl)
t.render(name="Me")
```

I want to modify template to have simply one line conditional. Something like this (in [jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) syntax):

```
Hello {% if name %} {{name}} {% else %} world {% endif %}
```

It seems like Mako needs a line before control structures. I tried put new line [with `\`](https://git.sr.ht/%7Esomenxavierb/cagen/commit/1ceb7b16547ea91fe41aa99adbd77ea013b4ed17) but it did not work:

```
tmpl = """% if name:\ Hello ${name} \ % else:\ Hello world\ % endif"""
```

Comment: I discovered it is a duplicated of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633028/mako-use-if-else-control-structure-in-one-line). Can anyone mark this question as duplicated?

Answer (score 0):

We need to use "\n":

```
tmpl = "% if name:\n Hello ${name}\n % else:\n Hello world\n % endif"
```

If we use file template, we need to expand "\n". As commented in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75132308/2755116) and [unicode Chapter in official Mako documentation](https://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/unicode.html), one solution could be:

```
t2 = Template(filename="prova.tmpl", output_encoding='utf-8')
result = t2.render(name="Me").decode("unicode_escape")
print(result)
```