# Why \n does not expand when read file but yes in built-in strings?

Tags: python, string, carriage-return

- If you run

  ```
  tmpl = "This is the first line\n And this is the second line"
  print("tmpl)
  ```

  you get

  ```
   This is the first line
   And this is the second line
  ```

  So you get a new line *expanded*.
- But if you write in a file, you will not get that:

  Put in `test.tmpl`:

  ```
  This is the first line\n And this is the second line
  ```

  and run

  ```
  with open("test.tmpl") as f:
      contents = f.read()
      print(contents)
  ```

  you get

  ```
  This is the first line\n And this is the second line
  ```

Why this behaviour? How can you get the the `contents` displays the same than `tmpl`?

Comment: if you `print(repr(contents))` you will see that it is escaped `This is the first line\\n And this is the second line` because it's not new-line char

Comment: The file contains a backslash followed by a letter n, not a newline character. A newline character in your file will appear as a new line.

Comment: Your test.tmpl does not contain a newline character. Maybe you wrote the file using a raw string or otherwise escaped the backslash. Show how you created the file content

Comment: @Pingu how can do that?

Comment: @buran How can I read unscaped, so?

Comment: @somenxavier, the question is how to write it there as new-line char. If you have `\n` in a plain text file that is NOT new-line char.

Comment: Try *contents = f.read().replace(r'\n', '\n')*

Comment: @Pingu: that will not work properly for escaped backslashes like in `r'\\n'`

Comment: @ThomasWeller True but that doesn't appear to be the case with the data shown by OP. Also note the word "try" as we cannot be absolutely certain what the data looks like. If was providing a definitive solution I would do so by way of an Answer rather than a Comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python string is interpreted by the Python interpreter. The Python interpreter knows what escape characters are and how to deal with them.

When reading a text file, you get the characters as they are. A newline in a text file consists of the characters 0x0D (CR; carriage return) and/or 0x0A (LF; line feed). You get that when pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard. If you want to consider escape characters in a text file, you need to [implement that yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4020539/480982).

Applied to your case:

```py
with open("test.tmpl") as f:
    contents = f.read()
    contents = bytes(contents, "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape")
    print(contents)
```

Comment: There is no way to escape characters automatically when read a file?

Comment: @somenxavier: I've added a link. It's not much code.

Comment: At least it's anti-intuitive behaviour

Comment: @somenxavier: That's not unintuitive for anyone, except for programmers. Nobody else than programmers cares about escape characters. So I guess you as a developer should adapt to the other 99% of text file users, not the other way round.

Comment: @somenxavier, if you write/create that file content manually, why would you use escape sequence `\n`, instead of new line? And if it is created programmatically, that means there is problem with how you write it and should change that, not how you read it.